# Test modal component within another component

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, react-testing-library, react-portal

I'm trying to test a component that should open its modal. Modal is a part of this component, but it's rendered with createPortal(). I first check if modal exist in the document and after button click if it appeared but test fails.

Component:

```
const [openModal, setOpenModal] = useState(false);

function Component() {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setOpenModal(true)}>Open Modal</button>
      <Modal open={openModal}/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Modal:

```
const Modal = ({ open, children }) => {
  return createPortal(
    <div style={{display: open ? "block" : "none"}} data-testid="modal">
      {children}
    </div>,
    document.getElementById("modals")
  );
};
```

Test:

```
test("component that opens modal", async () => {
  render(<Component />);
  const button = screen.getByText("Open Modal");
  const modal = screen.queryByTestId("modal");
  expect(modal).not.toBeInTheDocument();
  fireEvent.click(button);
  await waitFor(() => expect(modal).toBeInTheDocument()); // Fails
});
```

I tried to test it with `await waitFor(() => expect(modal).toBeInTheDocument())` and also with standard `expect(modal).toBeInTheDocument())`. I also tried to render modal without portal, but still had no effect on the test. Could you please explain how it should be tested?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of behavior is probably generating a new render, try using act

Some useful links: https://github.com/threepointone/react-act-examples/blob/master/sync.md

https://testing-library.com/docs/preact-testing-library/api/#act

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

After `fireEvent` try this and it will pass:

```
await waitFor(() => expect(modal));
```

This will pass if modal `id` is present in the view.